# Internet Explorer 11 SyntaxError in ckeditor.js

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

I am getting a weird issue only in IE11 - works fine when I turn emulator on for IE10 - where when I hover over my CKEditor, I receive literally hundreds of `SyntaxError ckeditor.js (129,54)`, sometimes the numbers in the quote is `(126,54)`.

The console errors shows when I hover the mouse into the ckeditor field, and returns a new but same error message every pixel I move the cursor. Hence why in a simple scroll or pass through with my cursor in the ckeditor field, I can get hundreds of errors.

My main issue at hand, is the ckeditor.js file is similar to this - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.3/ckeditor.js - in that it looks minified. Is there an un-miny version online anywhere?

Secondly, I am posting this to see if anyone has any obvious points I am overlooking, or advice for debugging CKeditor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is unminified version: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev.
You can clone the repository, be sure that you checkout to stable branch such as 4.7.3. Useful might be also install package with npm.
Then take a look into samples folder. There is regular `index.html` file which use local `ckeditor.js`, so you should be able to build similar test page for yourself and track the error.